# google+ api error forbidden 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-plus

I am using this url to get the accesstoken

```
http://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token?client_id=*********.ps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:49261/Default.aspx&client_secret=*******************
```

Here are the steps I'm using

Getting a code in authorization

```
 string url = string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}", AUTHORIZE, this.ConsumerKey, CALLBACK_URL);
 url += "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&response_type=code";
```

The above url returns a code and using that code I am using 
exchange the code for a accesstoken.

```
 http://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token?client_id=*********.ps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:49261/Default.aspx&client_secret=*******************
```

Here's my code to get the accesstoken

```
public void AccessTokenGet(string authToken)
        {
            this.Token = authToken;
            string accessTokenUrl = string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&client_secret={3}&code={4}",
            ACCESS_TOKEN, this.ConsumerKey, CALLBACK_URL, this.ConsumerSecret, authToken);

            string response = WebRequest(Method.GET, accessTokenUrl, String.Empty);

            if (response.Length > 0)
            {
                //Store the returned access_token
                NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);

                if (qs["access_token"] != null)
                {
                    this.Token = qs["access_token"];
                }
            }
        }


        public string WebRequest(Method method, string url, string postData)
        {

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
            StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
            string responseData = "";

            webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
            webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            webRequest.UserAgent = "[You user agent]";
            webRequest.Timeout = 20000;


            if (method == Method.POST)
            {
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                //POST the data.
                requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());

                try
                {
                    requestWriter.Write(postData);
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }

                finally
                {
                    requestWriter.Close();
                    requestWriter = null;
                }
            }

            responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);
            webRequest = null;
            return responseData;
        }


        public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            StreamReader responseReader = null;
            string responseData = "";

            try
            {
                responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
                responseReader.Close();
                responseReader = null;
            }

            return responseData;
        }
```

It fails in the WebResponseGet method. Returns a HTTP 403 forbidden
EDIT:
probably I wasn't clear earlier. To explain the error here's what its is
The code fails on its request for access token

```
error: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me is the endpoint for fetching a user's profile (see  [docs for people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)).  This is only callable *after* you get an access token.

The endpoint for actually getting the access token itself is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.  Depending on which OAuth2 flow you're wanting to use, the exact parameters you pass to that endpoint will differ slightly, but all of them are documented at http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html